# Error while trying t download an image Python3.4.5

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am new to python and just learning by watching videos from certain blogs. This is a program of downloading an image from internet which shows the following error

```
import random
import urllib.request

def download_web_image(url):
    name = random.randrange(1, 1000)
    full_name = str(name) + ".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)

download_web_image("https://www.thenewboston.com/images/homepage_images  /main_homepage_01.png")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bucky.py", line 2, in <module>
    import urllib.request
  File "/home/yuvi/pyth/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 69, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
    from email import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/email/utils.py", line 31, in <module>
    import urllib.parse
  File "/home/yuvi/pyth/urllib/parse.py", line 239, in <module>
    _DefragResultBase.url.__doc__ = """The URL with no fragment identifier."""
AttributeError: readonly attribute
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: @RoryDaulton seems like he copypasted from another SE question and copied the up/downvote and favorite button and the vote counter.

Comment: yeah actually I had posted in ubuntu community where they sugested this website so i copied the whole thing and pasted here @Rory Daulton